# Fragment or MapView?

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm developing an application that use Google Map API V2.... but i'm with a terrible doubt in my head: What should i use, Fragment or MapView?

In the example app that comes with the Google API it's used MapView, but in the developer's [site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start) they use Fragment.

So, what should i use? What the differences between they?

And, in case of MapView, can anyone show me how can i put a Marker in the map?

Thanks a lot...

Obs: I have searched... but not found the answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, are you planning to make difference between phone UI and tablet UI, if so I would use fragment.
I also prefer using fragment since it makes the UI smoother and more functional.

Answer (score 1):

`So, what should i use?`

only you can answer that

`What the differences`

`MapFragment` is just like any fragment, but shows a map

`MapActivity` is a new activity that shows the map

in either case you get the map the same by doing

```
GoogleMap map = getMap();
```

Comment: but com.google.android.maps.MapView don't have getMap().... i will use a Fragment....

Comment: no but `MapActivity` does which is what you need to use mapview

Comment: @ElvisOliveira `MapActivity` and `com.google.android.maps.MapView` are part of the deprecated Android API v1. If you use v2 MapView directly, you have to be careful to use proper package [`com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html).

Comment: thanks @MaciejGórski, you explained it to me now.... but why Google dont simply update the project example? I think it will resolve some problems before they happen...

Comment: @ElvisOliveira How about `extras/google/google_play_services/samples/maps/src/com/example/mapdemo/RawMapViewDemoActivity.java`?

Comment: @MaciejGórski... hum... but in the sample code that comes with the SDK (Google API) its use MapView..... thanks for show me that...